# Why won't my Volume Texture display correctly in camera view?

Tags: camera

I created the flame on the back by texturing a Volume Empty...

[image]

...However when I go to camera view it looks like so:

[image]

What's going on? No matter how I angle it & use "lock camera to view", it doesn't show up correctly in camera view.

The flame is apparently there (see image below), but it doesn't extend outward in camera view, as it correctly does in regular view.

[image]

Comment: It might have something to do with my Camera's clip start. I reduced it from .0001 to .1 & the flame shows up in the still image... However when I play the animation, I still can't get the flame to show up for the whole thing.  Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Also seems to work okay in Cycles, but not Eevee.  Maybe that's the answer?